# Custom user permission based on User Profile Model Filed Role

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i am creating a Todo list app using Django rest framework.

in this app only manager can post task in the list.
User Profile has a field named as a role.
I have a User Profile Model with extended User Model.

model.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=False)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=DEPARTMENT_CHOICES,default='technology')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ROLE_CHOICES,default='manager')
```

User Profile have a role field.

I want the only manager can post Task in my app.

How can I write custom user permission in order to achieve this?
Restricted to POST request only. All other requests can be permitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create a permission which subclasses `rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated` and add your logic in `has_permission(self, request, view)` ([see more](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions)).

If you only want it to be applied to `POST`, simply check the request's method and return `True` if it's a different method. Something like:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class CustomPermission(permissions.IsAuthenticated):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.user_profile.role == 'ADMIN' or request.method != 'POST':
            return True

        return False
```

Don't forget to include this permission in your view's `permission_classes`.

**PS:** I should warn you, though, it's a bit odd that you'd allow only admins to POST tasks while allowing everyone to PUT and DELETE on them. Maybe you mean you want to allow everyone in *safe_methods* only (GET, OPTIONS and HEAD)? If that's the case, replace `request.method != 'POST'` with `request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS`.

Comment: i have a UserProfile Model with OneToOne relation with User Model. so i think my request.user.user_profile is not recognized. ?

Comment: Add a `related_name` attribute to your relation. Like this: `user = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=False, related_name='user_profile')`. Then you will be able to access your user profile from your user.